# Fixed excel formula (not depending on moving cell)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In D2 cell I have a formula referring to D4 cell value.

[image]

Then, I drag&drop D4 cell from D4 to C4, and my D2 cell formula changed.

[image]

**How to "hardcode" this marked reference to D4 (resulting in 0*2=0)?**

Is it possible to make it work without vba?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
=indirect(address(4,4))*2
```

Comment: Works exactly the way I want. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use absolute reference like..

```
=$D$4*2
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you aren't doing a vlookup to reference the data (Which is the problem I'm having), try using an INDEX with the limits of excel's table of cells as the braces to prevent it from moving, like this:

=(INDEX($1:$1048576,4,4))*2

That prevents the reference from moving. =D